# Protractor is unable to click the links which are associated with $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to click a link which is associated with $timeout, which will be displayed only for few seconds. After clicking it opens a pop up and adds new message to list.

But as i went through https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/169, it says protractor waits for $timeout to finish. So can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to *turn the sync between Angular and Protractor off* and wait until you see the desired text. Something along these lines:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

# navigate to a page here

browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement($("#myid"), "some text"), 5000);
```

Comment: I need to click an element which will be present only for few seconds. After clicking the link it opens a pop up, which is not happening.

Comment: @Shivaraj sorry, there is not much more I can help with, without being able to reproduce the specific problem you have. I've just posted a generic answer to a generic question. Thanks.

Comment: browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; will not work when there are multiple broadcast events happening. Thanks @alecxe for replying

Comment: @Shivaraj well, from what we have in this topic now, I would say, you won't be able to catch this element appearing for a few seconds without turning the sync off..

Comment: yes.. But when i consider the below scenario  1) Fill the fields and submit some form, which will broadcast multiple events like   
* status message link, which is attached with $timeout and visible for only few seconds  
* a new message gets added to the message list in different widget  
2) Next when you click the status message link, then it should open the message as pop up with details  
It is making it diff to automate